# Transform .txt to proper .csv with custom delimiter with notepad++

Tags: wordpress, csv, import

This should be an easy one but I can't get it to work.

I have a TXT file like so:

```
TEXT1 TEXT1 TEXT1

...

TEXT2 TEXT2 TEXT2

...

TEXT3 TEXT3 TEXT3

...

(etc)
```

...where each TEXT is an article separated by `line-break / ... / line-break`, and I'd like to transform it into a simple CSV to import it into WordPress as posts.

I have replaced the three dots and line-breaks to commas, to commas and quotes, to commas and double quotes... but when I imported it never counts properly the number of articles, and it looks like it takes into account some rogue linebreaks inside the contents, as well as white spaces to divide the contents.

I'm using a good script to make the import called All Import Pro but their documentation do not say a word about my case.

So, is there something that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded to CSV a WordPress Blog and looked at the structure.

I then went to my file and created the Column Name "content".
I then replaced every line break / three dots / line-break with double quotes to start/end each article.

The import then worked.

Final structure:

```
Content
"TEXT1 TEXT1 TEXT1"
"TEXT2 TEXT2 TEXT2"
"TEXT3 TEXT3 TEXT3"
(etc)
```

Any internal line-break on the articles won't cause problems this way. I replaced all internal double quotes for single quotes just in case.